# tkinter checkbox selection affecting shapes

Tags: checkbox, tkinter

I am working from a book and have an exercise where the user selects a figure from a radio button and specifies whether it is filled by selecting a check button.
Struggling for days on what at first seemed like a simple exercise has me totally exhausted.  How do I use the checkbox called 'filled' to change the fill of the rectangle and oval shapes?
Any help is appreciated.

```
from tkinter import * 

class SelectShapes:
    def __init__(self):
        window = Tk() 
        window.title("Select Shapes") 

        self.canvas = Canvas(window, width = 500, height = 400, bg = "white" )
        self.canvas.pack()

        frame1 = Frame(window)
        frame1.pack()

        self.v1 = IntVar()
        btRectangle = Radiobutton(frame1, text = "Rectangle", variable = self.v1, value = 1, command = self.processRadiobutton)
        btOval = Radiobutton(frame1, text = "Oval", variable = self.v1, value = 2, command = self.processRadiobutton)
        btRectangle.grid(row = 2, column = 1)
        btOval.grid(row = 2, column = 2)

        self.v2 = IntVar()
        cbtFill = Checkbutton(frame1, text = "Fill", variable = self.v2, command = self.processCheckbutton)
        cbtFill.grid(row = 2, column = 3)


        window.mainloop()

    def processCheckbutton(self):
        if self.v2.get() == 1:
            self.v1["fill"] = "red"
        else:
            return False

    def processRadiobutton(self):
        if self.v1.get() == 1:
            self.canvas.delete("rect", "oval")
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(10, 10, 250, 200, tags = "rect")
            self.canvas.update()
        elif self.v1.get() == 2:
            self.canvas.delete("rect", "oval")
            self.canvas.create_oval(10, 10, 250, 200, tags = "oval")
            self.canvas.update()


SelectShapes()  # Create GUI
```

Comment: Your code example is incorrectly formatted.

Comment: I re-pasted it so its looks better.  Is that what you meant?

Comment: yes, it looks much better.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in your `processCheckbutton` function.  It looks like you're thinking of `self.v1` as a canvas object in some way, but it's not - it's just the `IntVar` storing the state of the `Checkbutton`.  You need to add a line there that changes the fill attribute of a canvas object.  To do so, you first need to save the ID of the current canvas object:

In the `processRadioButton` function:

```
        self.shapeID = self.canvas.create_rectangle(10, 10, 250, 200, tags = "rect")
#       ^^^^^^^^^^^^  save the ID of the object you create
```

and

```
        self.shapeID = self.canvas.create_oval(10, 10, 250, 200, tags = "oval")
#       ^^^^^^^^^^^^  save the ID of the object you create
```

And finally in the `processCheckbutton` function:

```
def processCheckbutton(self):
    if self.shapeID is not None:
        if self.v2.get() == 1:
            self.canvas.itemconfig(self.shapeID, fill="red")
#                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^  use the saved ID to access and modify the canvas object.
        else:
            self.canvas.itemconfig(self.shapeID, fill="")
#                                                     ^^ Change the fill back to transparent if you uncheck the checkbox
```

Comment: Great.  Your explanation and example are perfect for my little brain.  I fully understand what is going on.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad to help - if this solved your problem, consider marking it as "accepted" so it's easy for future readers to tell that the problem is solved.